# How do I get WebGuy->fillField to work in Codeception acceptance test?

Tags: codeception, acceptance

I hope someone can help me as I'm really just about to headbutt my desk on this one :-(

I'm trying to get fillFIeld to work, but I just cannot seem to make it knuckle down.

seeInField works on the same form field so I reckon my targeting etc. is all good.

I've even written an incredibly basic test to try an rule EVERYTHING ELSE.

The HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="SearchForm" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="abc" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

The test...

```
//INSTANTIATE WEB GUY
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);

//DEFINE TEST
$I->wantTo('search from home');

//GET ON THE HOME PAGE
$I->amOnPage('/'); 
$I->seeInField('search', 'abc');
$I->fillField('search', 'def');
$I->seeInField('search', 'def');
```

The output...

```
Acceptance Tests (1) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: PhpBrowser, WebHelper
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to search from home (Search_From_Home_Page_Cept.php)       
Scenario:
* I am on page "/__staging/"
* I see in field "search","abc"
* I fill field "search","def"
* I see in field "search","def"
FAIL

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 25 ms, Memory: 12.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to search from home in Search_From_Home_Page_Cept.php
Sorry, I couldn't see in field "search","def":
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'def'
+'abc'

Scenario Steps:
4. I see in field "search","def"
3. I fill field "search","def"
2. I see in field "search","abc"
1. I am on page "/__staging/"

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

I'm clearly missing something very obvious, but having spent a couple of hours trawling forums and not finding anything that solves it I NEED HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute selector to select input element by it's name attribute:

```
$I->fillField('input[name=search]', 'def');
```

Comment: No banana I'm afraid. I might have to make a simple static html page to test this on so I can rule out something in our site causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an Id to the field.

```
<input type="text" id="search_input" name="search" value="abc" />


$I->seeInField('#search_input', 'abc');
$I->fillField('#search_input', 'def');
$I->seeInField('#search_input', 'def');
```

I hope this work.

Comment: Unfortunately not...
    `$I->amOnPage($test_url); 
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl($test_url); 
    $I->fillField('#search', 'def');
    $I->seeInField('#search', 'def');`

results in 

`Scenario Steps:
9. I see in field "#search","def"
8. I fill field "#search","def"
7. I see in current url "/__staging/"
6. I am on page "/__staging/"`

Comment: I wish you could do line break in these comments